# parallel check md5 file

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel, md5sum

I have a md5sum file containing lots of lines. I want to use GNU parallel to accelerate the md5sum checking process. In the md5sum, when no file input, it will take the md5 string from stdin. I tried this:

`cat checksums.md5 | parallel md5sum -c {}`

But getting this error:

`md5sum 445350b414a8031d9dd6b1e68a6f2367  testing.gz: No such file or directory`

How can I parallel the md5sum checking?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming checksums.md5 has the format:

```
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  My file name
```

Run:

```
cat checksums.md5 | parallel --pipe -N1 md5sum -c
```

If your files are small: -N100

If that does not speed up your processing make sure your disks are fast enough: md5sum can process 500 MB/s. `iostat -dkx 1` can tell you if your disks are a bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried to both --block and -N and use top to check num of cpu usage. --block only uses 1 cpu regardless of what value I put (1M, 10M, 100M). -N1 used up a lot of cpus, -N10 uses only a few cpus and -N0 & -N100 use only 1 cpu. Not sure why, but will use -N1 in the future.

Comment: The reason is that you only only have few files (i.e. the size of checksums.md5 is far less than 1 MB)

Answer (score 1):

You need option `--pipe`. In this mode parallel splits stdin into blocks and supplies each block to the command via stdin, see `man parallel` for details:

```
cat checksums.md5 | parallel --pipe md5sum -c -
```

By default size of the block is 1 MB, can be changed with `--block` option.